# adding svg rectangle to dom using js

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, svg, jquery-selectors

I would add a rectangle as on each Node element

the `rect` is added only in the last element.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {


  let rect : NodeList = this.synoptic.nativeElement.querySelectorAll("#stops g");
  let rect2 = document.createElementNS('','rect');
  rect2.setAttribute("fill","none");
  rect.forEach((elm : Node) => {
    console.log(elm.firstChild) #### Well selecting the first element
    elm.insertBefore(rect2,elm.firstChild);
    console.log(elm) ####rect  added
  })
### rect is awailable only in the last elm
}
```

Edit I'm using angular And my code is running inside `ngAfterViewInit()` hook

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8wgbws?file=src/app/app.component.ts) a stackblitz demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way by adding `namespace` and attributes required for `rect`

```js
(function() {

  let rect = document.querySelectorAll("#stops g");
  rect.forEach(e => {
    let rect2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
    rect2.setAttribute("fill", "#000");
    rect2.setAttribute('x', e.getAttribute('x'));
    rect2.setAttribute('y', e.getAttribute('y'));
    rect2.setAttribute('height', '50');
    rect2.setAttribute('width', '50');
    e.appendChild(rect2);
  });

})();
```

```html
<svg id="stops" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g x="0" y="0"></g>
<g x="100" y="100"></g>
</svg>
```

[Angular Working Fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5qp2gz)

Comment: rect is a NodeList , your example is working with only one Node. add to that I would insert rect element as first child

Comment: It's the samething that I'm doing but not working for me

Comment: you mean this solution does not work in your environment?

Comment: yes, I have edited my code to mention that I'm using Angular

Comment: yeah, that's alright. This should work well in angular. Can you do a sample of what you are trying on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5qp2gz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196134/discussion-between-nidhin-joseph-and-infodev).

Answer (score 0):

The SVG namespace is 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', and not the empty string.

Additionally a rect with fill none won't be visible, it either needs a fill or a stroke and appears to have neither specified.

Finally it needs a non-zero width and height.

Comment: I have added the namespace but nothing happens

Comment: I have Updated my question